# Cannot write sorted rows in informix 12.10

Tags: out-of-memory, shared-memory, informix

When I try to execute a view in an Informix database, I am getting an error message like:

```
SQL Error [IX000]: Cannot write sorted rows
ISAM error: no free disk space for sort
```

My system configuration is

OS: Windows server 2019

Ram:32 GB

Informix Version : 12.10

DB Space : 2TB

below adding the view definition.

```html
create view "informix".fan_sensor_view (localcol,tef_1,tef_2,tef_3,tef_4,tef_5,tef_6,tef_7,tef_8,tvf_1,tvf_1a,tvf_2,tvf_2a,tvf_3,tvf_3a,tvf_4,tvf_4a,tvf_5,tvf_6,station,corridor) as 
select x0.sti_energy_tef_localcol ,TO_CHAR (round(x0.tef_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x0.tef_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x0.tef_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x0.tef_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x1.tvf_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x1.tvf_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x1.tvf_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x1.tvf_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'STI' ,'Corridor2' from ("informix".sti_energy_tef x0 join "informix".sti_energy_tvf x1 on (EXTEND (x0.sti_energy_tef_localcol ,year to second) = EXTEND (x1.sti_energy_tvf_localcol ,year to second) ) ) 
union select x2.sat_energy_tef_localcol ,TO_CHAR (round(x2.tef_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x2.tef_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x2.tef_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x2.tef_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x3.tvf_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x3.tvf_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x3.tvf_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x3.tvf_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'SAT' ,'Corridor2' from ("informix".sat_energy_tef x2 join "informix".sat_energy_tvf x3 on (EXTEND (x2.sat_energy_tef_localcol ,year to second) = EXTEND (x3.sat_energy_tvf_localcol ,year to second) ) ) 
union select x4.sae_energy_tef_localcol ,TO_CHAR (round(x4.tef_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x4.tef_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x4.tef_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x4.tef_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x5.tvf_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x5.tvf_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x5.tvf_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x5.tvf_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'SAE' ,'Corridor2' from ("informix".sae_energy_tef x4 join "informix".sae_energy_tvf x5 on (EXTEND (x4.sae_energy_tef_localcol ,year to second) = EXTEND (x5.sae_energy_tvf_localcol ,year to second) ) ) 
union select x6.ssn_energy_tef_localcol ,TO_CHAR (round(x6.tef_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x6.tef_2_fan_vibrationmm_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x6.tef_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x6.tef_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x7.tvf_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x7.tvf_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x7.tvf_3_fan_vibrationmm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x7.tvf_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'SSN' ,'Corridor2' from ("informix".ssn_energy_tef x6 join "informix".ssn_energy_tvf x7 on (EXTEND (x6.ssn_energy_tef_localcol ,year to second) = EXTEND (x7.ssn_energy_tvf_localcol ,year to second) ) ) 
union select x8.spc_energy_tef_localcol ,TO_CHAR (round(x8.tef_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x8.tef_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x8.tef_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x8.tef_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x9.tvf_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x9.tvf_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x9.tvf_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x9.tvf_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'SPC' ,'Corridor2' from ("informix".spc_energy_tef x8 join "informix".spc_energy_tvf x9 on (EXTEND (x8.spc_energy_tef_localcol ,year to second) = EXTEND (x9.spc_energy_tvf_localcol ,year to second) ) )
union select x10.skm_energy_tef_localcol ,TO_CHAR (round(x10.tef_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x10.tef_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x10.tef_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x10.tef_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x11.tvf_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x11.tvf_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x11.tvf_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x11.tvf_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'SKM' ,'Corridor2' from ("informix".skm_energy_tef x10 join "informix".skm_energy_tvf x11 on (EXTEND (x10.skm_energy_tef_localcol ,year to second) = EXTEND (x11.skm_energy_tvf_localcol ,year to second) ) )
union select x12.snp_energy_tef_localcol ,TO_CHAR (round(x12.tef_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x12.tef_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x12.tef_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x12.tef_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x13.tvf_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x13.tvf_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x13.tvf_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x13.tvf_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'SNP' ,'Corridor2' from ("informix".snp_energy_tef x12 join "informix".snp_energy_tvf x13 on (EXTEND (x12.snp_energy_tef_localcol ,year to second) = EXTEND (x13.snp_energy_tvf_localcol ,year to second) ) ) 
union select x14.seg_energy_tef_localcol ,TO_CHAR (round(x14.tef_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x14.tef_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x14.tef_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x14.tef_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x15.tvf_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x15.tvf_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x15.tvf_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x15.tvf_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'SEG' ,'Corridor2' from ("informix".seg_energy_tef x14 join "informix".seg_energy_tvf x15 on (EXTEND (x14.seg_energy_tef_localcol ,year to second) = EXTEND (x15.seg_energy_tvf_localcol ,year to second) ) )
union select x16.ssa_energy_tef_localcol ,TO_CHAR (round(x16.tef_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x16.tef_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x16.tef_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x16.tef_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x17.tvf_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x17.tvf_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x17.tvf_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x17.tvf_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'SSA' ,'Corridor1' from ("informix".ssa_energy_tef x16 join "informix".ssa_energy_tvf x17 on (EXTEND (x16.ssa_energy_tef_localcol ,year to second) = EXTEND (x17.ssa_energy_tvf_localcol ,year to second) ) ) 
union select x18.scr_energy_tef_localcol ,TO_CHAR (round(x18.tef_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x18.tef_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x18.tef_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x18.tef_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x19.tvf_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x19.tvf_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x19.tvf_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x19.tvf_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'SCR' ,'Corridor1' from ("informix".scr_energy_tef x18 join "informix".scr_energy_tvf x19 on (EXTEND (x18.scr_energy_tef_localcol ,year to second) = EXTEND (x19.scr_energy_tvf_localcol ,year to second) ) ) 
union select x20.ste_energy_tef_localcol ,TO_CHAR (round(x20.tef_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x20.tef_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x20.tef_3_fan_vibrationmm_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x20.tef_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x21.tvf_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x21.tvf_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x21.tvf_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x21.tvf_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'STE' ,'Corridor1' from ("informix".ste_energy_tef x20 join "informix".ste_energy_tvf x21 on (EXTEND (x20.ste_energy_tef_localcol ,year to second) = EXTEND (x21.ste_energy_tvf_localcol ,year to second) ) ) 
union select x22.sgm_energy_tef_localcol ,TO_CHAR (round(x22.tef_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x22.tef_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x22.tef_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x22.tef_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x23.tvf_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x23.tvf_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x23.tvf_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x23.tvf_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'SGM' ,'Corridor1' from ("informix".sgm_energy_tef x22 join "informix".sgm_energy_tvf x23 on (EXTEND (x22.sgm_energy_tef_localcol ,year to second) = EXTEND (x23.sgm_energy_tvf_localcol ,year to second) ) ) 
union select x24.stl_energy_tef_localcol ,TO_CHAR (round(x24.tef_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x24.tef_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x24.tef_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x24.tef_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x25.tvf_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x25.tvf_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x25.tvf_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x25.tvf_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'STL' ,'Corridor1' from ("informix".stl_energy_tef x24 join "informix".stl_energy_tvf x25 on (EXTEND (x24.stl_energy_tef_localcol ,year to second) = EXTEND (x25.stl_energy_tvf_localcol ,year to second) ) ) 
union select x26.sli_energy_tef_localcol ,TO_CHAR (round(x26.tef_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x26.tef_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x26.tef_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x26.tef_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x27.tvf_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x27.tvf_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x27.tvf_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x27.tvf_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'SLI' ,'Corridor1' from ("informix".sli_energy_tef x26 join "informix".sli_energy_tvf x27 on (EXTEND (x26.sli_energy_tef_localcol ,year to second) = EXTEND (x27.sli_energy_tvf_localcol ,year to second) ) ) 
union select x28.sge_energy_tef_localcol ,TO_CHAR (round(x28.tef_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x28.tef_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x28.tef_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x28.tef_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x29.tvf_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x29.tvf_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x29.tvf_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x29.tvf_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'SGE' ,'Corridor1' from ("informix".sge_energy_tef x28 join "informix".sge_energy_tvf x29 on (EXTEND (x28.sge_energy_tef_localcol ,year to second) = EXTEND (x29.sge_energy_tvf_localcol ,year to second) ) ) 
union select x30.scc_c1_energy_tef_localcol ,TO_CHAR (round(x30.tef_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x30.tef_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x30.tef_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x30.tef_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x31.tvf_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x31.tvf_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x31.tvf_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x31.tvf_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'SCC_C1' ,'Corridor1' from ("informix".scc_c1_energy_tef x30 join "informix".scc_c1_energy_tvf x31 on (EXTEND (x30.scc_c1_energy_tef_localcol ,year to second) = EXTEND (x31.scc_c1_energy_tvf_localcol ,year to second) ) ) 
union select x32.shc_energy_tef_localcol ,TO_CHAR (round(x32.tef_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x32.tef_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x32.tef_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x32.tef_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x33.tvf_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x33.tvf_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x33.tvf_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x33.tvf_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'SHC' ,'Corridor1' from ("informix".shc_energy_tef x32 join "informix".shc_energy_tvf x33 on (EXTEND (x32.shc_energy_tef_localcol ,year to second) = EXTEND (x33.shc_energy_tvf_localcol ,year to second) ) ) 
union select x34.swa_energy_tef_localcol ,TO_CHAR (round(x34.tef_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x34.tef_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x34.tef_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x34.tef_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x35.tvf_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x35.tvf_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x35.tvf_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x35.tvf_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'SWA' ,'Corridor1' from ("informix".swa_energy_tef x34 join "informix".swa_energy_tvf x35 on (EXTEND (x34.swa_energy_tef_localcol ,year to second) = EXTEND (x35.swa_energy_tvf_localcol ,year to second) ) ) 
union select x36.stc_energy_tvf_localcol ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x36.tvf_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x36.tvf_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x36.tvf_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x36.tvf_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'STC' ,'Corridor1' from "informix".stc_energy_tvf x36  
union select x37.str_energy_tvf_localcol ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x37.tvf_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x37.tvf_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x37.tvf_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x37.tvf_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'STR' ,'Corridor1' from "informix".str_energy_tvf x37  
union select x38.sma_energy_tef_localcol ,TO_CHAR (round(x38.tef_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x38.tef_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x38.tef_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x38.tef_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x39.tvf_1_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x39.tvf_1a_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x39.tvf_2_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x39.tvf_2a_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x39.tvf_3_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x39.tvf_3a_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x39.tvf_4_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x39.tvf_4a_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'SMA' ,'Corridor1' from ("informix".sma_energy_tef x38 join "informix".sma_energy_tvf x39 on (EXTEND (x38.sma_energy_tef_localcol ,year to second) = EXTEND (x39.sma_energy_tvf_localcol ,year to second) ) ) 
union select x40.scc_c2_energy_tef_localcol ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x40.tef_5_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x40.tef_6_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x40.tef_7_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x40.tef_8_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,'NA' ,TO_CHAR (round(x41.tvf_5_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),TO_CHAR (round(x41.tvf_6_fan_vibration_mm_per_s , 1 ) ),'SCC_C2' ,'Corridor2' from ("informix".scc_c2_energy_tef x40 join "informix".scc_c2_energy_tvf x41 on (EXTEND (x40.scc_c2_energy_tef_localcol ,year to second) = EXTEND (x41.scc_c2_energy_tvf_localcol ,year to second) ) );
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: There should be a secondary 'ISAM' error number too.  That may provide some insight.  It could be that you've run out of space in temporary dbspaces, or on the main `/tmp` file system (which might be the same as the root file system).  It is most likely a disk space problem rather than a memory problem.  If we are going to help resolve this, you are going to need to provide a lot more information about your setup.  Do you have any idea how much data you are sorting?

Comment: I assume "execute a view" means "execute a query using (referencing) a view".  At some point, it might become relevant to see the view definition and the query you're executing against the view. In the short term though, looking at your disk space on the system is probably more relevant.

Comment: thanks for your inputs.I have updated the question.

Comment: Since the view is using "union", I believe that requires a sort of everything returned by each select to remove any duplicates.  I'd suggest monitoring the space where the server is doing sorts to see if it is running out of space.  If the sorting is happening in the server configured space it would be the chunks for the dbspaces listed in DBSPACETEMP from the $ONCONFIG file (so monitor free space using onstat -d while query running).  If not using database configured space, I believe it then uses windows filesystem space and defaults to C:\TEMP.

Comment: my Informix Tempdbs file having only 57 MB size. So i created a separate tempdb space with 300 MB and i have updated the same in the ONCONFIG file also. Now I'm able to execute the query without any issue. Thanks for the support.